# Databricks, save a logistic regression to an object to be able to call it from another notebook

Tags: object, databricks, azure-databricks

I fitted to my data a logistic regression, in another notebook i am trying to predict the probabilities of the previously fitted function.

I would not like to call the all notebook and run everything every single time, i just would like to save the fitted logreg in an object or something like that and only call that in the other notebook on databriks.

This is my function:

> log_test_var = logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

from "gaming" notebook
And I would like to save this log_test_var somewhere to predict my X column values from clean_text notebook

> y_pred = log_test_var.predict(X)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your findings and post it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to call particular variable directly.

**Workaround:-**

Use `%run` function to call a notebook inside another notebook.

In below screenshot you can see I have created variable in parent notebook.

[image]

To access variable from parent notebook, I have used `%run notebook_name`

[image]

This method is suitable if you want to define a notebook that holds all the constant variables or a centralized shared function library. And you want to refer to them in the calling or child notebook.

You can refer this [article](https://azureops.org/articles/call-a-notebook-from-another-notebook-in-databricks/) by PAVAN BANGAD